# Why do I get blocked on CORS when trying to access a public API?

Tags: angularjs, api, cors

I'm trying to access the government of Ontarios COVID-19 cases CKAN API via my AngularJS web application. However, this request:

```
var url = "https://data.ontario.ca/api/3/action/datastore_search?q=jones&resource_id=455fd63b-603d-4608-8216-7d8647f43350"
         return $http.get(url).then(function (data) {
             console.log(data)
             return data;
         }); 
     };
```

Is met with with response:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://data.ontario.ca/api/3/action/datastore_search?q=jones&resource_id=455fd63b-603d-4608-8216-7d8647f43350' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

The website gives this example for accessing the API via JavaScript:

```
var data = {
          resource_id: '455fd63b-603d-4608-8216-7d8647f43350', // the resource id
          limit: 5, // get 5 results
          q: 'jones' // query for 'jones'
        };
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://data.ontario.ca/api/3/action/datastore_search',
          data: data,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function(data) {
            alert('Total results found: ' + data.result.total)
          }
        });
```

How can I successfully make a request to this api from my AngularJS web application?

Comment: They may have misconfigured CORS headers, the only way to fix it is to let the administrators know to add CORS headers to each response for that API, there's nothing you can do from JavaScript side to overcome it. What you can do instead is create your own backend server, send requests from your backend server to the API, then relay the responses from that backend server to your frontend code, and of course, you have to make your backend server CORS-friendly to your frontend code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using a [JSONP](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) request instead of a standard GET.

```
var url = "https://data.ontario.ca/api/3/action/datastore_search?q=jones&resource_id=455fd63b-603d-4608-8216-7d8647f43350"
         return $http.jsonp($sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url)).then(function (data) {
             return data;
         });
```

Comment: Does $sce.trustAsResourceUrl add headers for a CORS request?...or is that what $http.jsonp is doing?